# Icon not showing preview vs code

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

Can anyone what is wrong here and how to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problems since I upgraded flutter I guess it's a problem either with vs code either with the newest flutter. I suggest you to see the icons through **[the flutter site](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Icons-class.html)**.